# Get Errors when adding a Service Reference to a project

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, visual-studio-2022, service-reference

I have built a Visual Studio project to consume a a 3rd party web service. The goal is to export CSV data. This is my first time consuming a web service so not sure what I am doing.

Here is the information that the web service has provided me (some info changed to protect my data):

Web Services Page, WSDL, and DataSource for Web Services Export:

https://reportservices.credtest.com/reports/ExportService.asmx

Encrypted Connection String:

GG3FakeStringgvwkdR4aCjKiu591-aUB2cfN18cYlNyqcpLD0V291y1gnZawA__

Query for Dataset Export:

```
<Query>
    <SoapAction>
        https://reportservices.credtest.com/ExportDataSet
    </SoapAction> 
    <Method Namespace="https://reportservices.credtest.com/" Name="ExportDataSet"> 
        <Parameters> 
            <Parameter Name="connection" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
            GG3FakeStringgvwkdR4aCjKiu591-aUB2cfN18cYlNyqcpLD0V291y1gnZawA__
            </DefaultValue>
        </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="start_date" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="end_date" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param1" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param2" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param3" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
        </Parameters> 
    </Method> 
        <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true"> 
        ExportDataSetResponse{}/ExportDataSetResult{}/diffgram{}/NewDataSet{}/Table{CPT_Code,Description,Other_Code,CPT_Modifier,Service_ID,Service,Service_Description,Program_ID,Program,Pgm_Dsc,Start_Minutes,End_Minutes,Matrix_ID,Start_Age,End_Age,Claim_Format,Credential_Group,RollUp_Code,Rate,Deaf_Rate,Fixed_Units,First_Unit_Minutes,Unit_Minutes,Unit_Multiplier} 
        </ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Query for XML Export:

```
<Query>
    <SoapAction>
        https://reportservices.credtest.com/ExportXML
    </SoapAction> 
    <Method Namespace="https://reportservices.credtest.com/" Name="ExportXML"> 
        <Parameters> 
            <Parameter Name="connection" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                    GG3FakeStringgvwkdR4aCjKiu591-aUB2cfN18cYlNyqcpLD0V291y1gnZawA__

                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="start_date" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="end_date" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param1" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param2" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
            <Parameter Name="custom_param3" Type="String">
                <DefaultValue>
                </DefaultValue>
            </Parameter> 
        </Parameters> 
    </Method> 
    <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true"> 
        ExportXMLResponse{}/ExportXMLResult{}/diffgram{}/NewDataSet{}/Table{CPT_Code,Description,Other_Code,CPT_Modifier,Service_ID,Service,Service_Description,Program_ID,Program,Pgm_Dsc,Start_Minutes,End_Minutes,Matrix_ID,Start_Age,End_Age,Claim_Format,Credential_Group,RollUp_Code,Rate,Deaf_Rate,Fixed_Units,First_Unit_Minutes,Unit_Minutes,Unit_Multiplier} 
    </ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Here is the description of what is happening.

Every time I try to add a Connected service I get an error, either when adding the service (WCF) or when doing a build (gRPC or OpenAPI).

I go to Connected Services > Manage Connected Services

This opens the Service References (OpenAPI, gRPC, WCF Web Service) window.
I click on “Add a new service reference”. This opens the Add Service Reference window and shows 3 choices to pick from (OpenAPI, gRPC, WCF Web Service).
I have tried both OpenAPI and gRPC and get errors when doing a build.
WCF gives me an error during the

If I choose Open API then the “Add a new OpenAPI service reference” window opens.
I fill out the form with the following information:

URL: https://reportservices.credtest.com/reports/ExportService.asmx (link changed to protect my data)
Namespace: CredNS
Class Name: CredCN
Code Generation Language: C#

Severity    : Error
Code: MSB3073

Description: The command ""C:\Users\dwoodard.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.0.5\build../tools/Win/NSwag.exe" openapi2csclient /className:CredCN /namespace:CredNS /input:C:\Users\dwoodard\source\repos\CredibleCoreWebApp\CredibleCoreWebApp\OpenAPIs\ExportService2.asmx /output:obj\ExportService2Client.cs " exited with code -1

Project CredibleCoreWebApp
File: C:\Users\dwoodard.nuget\packages\nswag.apidescription.client\13.0.5\build\NSwag.ApiDescription.Client.targets

Line    28
Column   5
Suppression State

If I choose gRPC then the “Add a new gRPC service reference” window opens.
I fill out the form with the following information:

URL: https://reportservices.credtest.com/reports/ExportService.asmx
Select the type of class to be generated: Client (I have also tried server and “Client and Server”)

I get the result “Successfully added service Reference(s)”.
If I click on “view generated code” then I get the following error:
Unable to get the generated codefiles for gRPC service reference ExportService2. You may need to build the project first.

I immediately do a build and get 82 errors.
Error #1:
Severity    : Error
Code:

Description: \src\github\grpc\workspace_protoc_windows_x64\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\parser.cc:648] No syntax specified for the proto file: Protos/ExportService2.asmx. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)

Project: CredibleCoreWebApp

File: C:\Users\dwoodard\source\repos\CredibleCoreWebApp\CredibleCoreWebApp[libprotobuf WARNING T

Line: 1
Column: 1
Suppression State:

The many errors following are like this:
Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
Need space between number and identifier.
"e" must be followed by exponent.

WCF Gives errors when trying to add so never succeeds.
I enter the URI: https://reportservices.credtest.com/reports/ExportService.asmx
Click GO
Services: reports/ExportService.asmx (automatically populated)
Status: Warning: One or more errors occurred.
Error Details:
Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.credtest.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='ExportService']/wsdl:port[@name='ExportServiceHttpPost']
Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.\r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.credtest.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ExportServiceHttpPost']
Cannot import wsdl:port\r\nDetail: \r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.credtest.com/']/wsdl:service[@name='ExportService']/wsdl:port[@name='ExportServiceHttpGet']
Cannot import wsdl:binding\r\nDetail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.\r\nXPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='https://www.credtest.com/']/wsdl:binding[@name='ExportServiceHttpGet']